# Microsoft Access linked table (ASE) with trigger error

Tags: ms-access, triggers, odbc, ms-access-2016, linked-tables

I have in Microsoft Access a linked table to an ASE Server.
On the server side, the table has no primary key or identity columns.
And has a trigger on insert that validates new entries, so that when the entry is not validated it deletes the entry from the table and writes to "table"_ERR to let the users know what error was produced.

When linking it to Access a composite key is created using 10 columns.

I have this same setup in 10 different tables (all with triggers all linked to Access)

In this particular table when trying to insert/append records to the table through Access i always get the error message:

> Single-row update/delete affected more than one row of a linked table. Unique index contains duplicate values.

This error occurs when both table and table_ERR are empty and i'm only trying to insert 1 record.

If I disable the trigger i have no problem inserting records through Access

I have similar triggers in other tables that are working correctly.
What can be causing this issue and does anyone know how to solve this?

I have read that MS Access can mess up the @@identity, even so none of the solutions presented online seem to work.

links : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/McHdRpPKMhs/SlyObU8w7JMJ

[Stop Access from using wrong identity when appending to linked table on SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644195/stop-access-from-using-wrong-identity-when-appending-to-linked-table-on-sql-serv)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: if i try to insert the records directly from a management software (like Aqua Data Studio) there are no erros

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more specifics about your data itself, it is difficult to say why this might be happening.

However, it sounds like in this specific instance for this specific linked table, your 10 columns are not unique enough to prevent non-distinct rows from being selected.

Suggested fixes:

1. Add a **primary key**. Honestly, probably the best and easiest choice.
2. If for some reason you cannot add a new column to (or alter) your table; you may be able to re-link your table, and re-choose your 10 columns so that they are *more* unique.
3. Beyond that, I think we would need more information.

Just out of curiousity, what is the reason for having no key?

Comment: the table has no key has it is used only has a "transfer data" table;
end-users link an excel into the access file and then copy-> paste append to it , and on the last day of the month that data is used in other calcs

Comment: Further more the problem really is in the trigger; if i remove the trigger there is no error message displayed with the exact same setup