# MS Access <> SQL Server : save current record which creates GUID in SQL and go back to this record

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

The title is maybe not the best. My current setting: MS Access frontend with a SQL Server backend.

The SQL Server backend will create the PK with a GUID as soon the row is saved.

I need to save my record and go back to that record to use the created PK GUID.

When I do a `Me.Refresh` or `Me.Requery`, it will loose the connection to the record showing `#Name?` on all fields.

I need to get to GUID because I want to upload a file which is done in a FILESTREAM table and the link to the content table is done via the GUID of the content table.

So I need the content table GUID but as the record is not yet saved, I don't have one.

How to save the record, get its GUID and "stay" on that record?

I tried following which is not working:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord 'Here it will show '#Name? on all fields
Me.Refresh
```

Comment: Maybe you can create the GUID? Then you could pass that to sql server for both inserts. I hope that your GUID which is likely your primary key is not also the clustered index.

Comment: @Sean As long as you use `NEWSEQUENTIALID` or some other way to assign sequential GUIDs, I don't really see a problem with a GUID being the clustered index.

Comment: @ErikA true that using NEWSEQUENTIALID would minimize the fragmentation but then why bother such a wide key? At that point it loses all the benefits of a guid and maintains the downsides.

Comment: @SeanLange: Yes I did this now and created the GUID directly within Access. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Me.Requery` instead of `Me.Refresh` and hope you stay on the same record. You can, of course, navigate to the last record, which opens a small door for race conditions (someone could in theory insert a record between you saving yours and you requerying).

Access does strange things to add records and then fetch the default data, as can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666197/7296893). It doesn't play well with GUID columns (or, really, anything that isn't a numeric identity primary key column without triggers). By forcing a requery you refetch all data.

Alternatively, you can bind the form to an ADO recordset and work with that, but that approach has some problems on its own, such as trouble with the built-in refresh/filter/sort options.